# PHP include make the whole page appear?

Tags: php, html

Okay, my code is simple:

```
<?php include 'formvalidation.php'; 
echo $name; ?>
```

I want to make only the `$name` appear, but the whole `'formvalidation.php'` shows up.

How can I fix that?

Comment: If the included file contains html tags, it will be shown in included page for sure.

Comment: use session or post otherwise you will face the same problem since its contains html

Comment: You can give Ajax a try, that'll be your best bet.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ajax - this is PHP on the server side.  It's a valid noob question.

Comment: @airtech It has everything to do with Ajax. OP wants his/her cake and eat it too. By using Ajax, the form gets submitted, form disappears then echo's the name; *done deal*. Oh, and maybe a dash of JS too ;) I think it's a good solution, if not the best one at that. Plus, we don't know what OP's form looks like. All we have is two lines of code to play with; it's anybody's guess.

Comment: @Fred - There is no javascript here, hence no AJAX.  He's not asking anything about AJAX code at all.  This could be a static page that is created by PHP for all we know.  You're guessing that he's validating a form through an AJAX call to here - but I'm not sure where you are getting that from.  I have a ton of forms (non ajax) that do form validation through server and client side on normal form submissions.

Comment: @airtech As I said, it's anybody's guess. OP hasn't provided enough information to give a concrete answer, it's a noob question as you said, yet a **bad** one at that not to mention **unclear**. Re-read the question again and be honest, it tells us nothing. If I had to bet my bottom dollar, it would be at a horse track.

Comment: @Fred It does have enough info.  He states what his code is, what it's displaying, and what he wants it to do.  In fact, there are 5 well worded answers to his problem as stated.  So 5 people, not to mentioned those who didn't post, got the question just fine.  I think it's just you :)  Of course he hasn't responded to anybody, accepted any answers, or clarified anything either.  :)  So, you may get me modding this one down too for unresponsiveness and being stupid.

Comment: @airtech *Yep, pretty much*. OP leaves and has us talking about it instead of getting into the convos; ***classic "post and leave, will pick up my dinner on the way out"***. Glad I didn't touch this one. Oh well, *let the games begin* ;)

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of all the comment you guys make, I'm learning php and don't know how to do it or don't know anyone that I can ask, so I went here and hoped for some helps. I may not asked in the right way, but that doesn't means I don't read your answers. And I didn't have enough reputation to increase yours, and now what?
Don't understand why you devs becomes such kind of, I don't know how to say it, the kind who prefer watching others feels bad instead of helping them, and then bad mouth about them to feel good about yourself.

Comment: and sorry for didn't add enough details in it, I thought that if I said too much, people might misunderstand what I want to ask. Sorry that I posted this and then leaves, after this question, I have school for 5 hours until now.

Comment: You guys might ignore me now, but I'll say what I think I should anyway. I want that after I pressed the button, the function I had written will be excute to check the input, and then if the input is right, it'll redirect to another page, which can display the input. Guess that I should learn more about superglobal variables, and be more careful the next time I want to ask somethings.

Comment: @FuukaAdachi For some reason, I had a feeling that is what you wanted to do. Had I known that ahead of time, I would have been able to give you an "answer" on how to achieve your goal. When posting a question, you need to provide more details and more code if at all possible. If you wish to redirect, there are a few ways to do it, but the most common method in PHP is a header. Without knowing which variables are previously assigned to the name field, is still a bit hard to give you a definite answer. Post your code for the form if you want a definite answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be more careful from now on, I didn't know I can do that :) And is there a way that I can thanks others answer? I don't think commenting "thanks" those is the right way. I want to say thanks to Adam, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I want that after I pressed the button, the function I had written will be excute to check the input, and then if the input is right, it'll redirect to another page, which can display the input."*

If you wish to redirect after a form has been submitted and show a name afterwards, you will need to use [**sessions**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) and a [**header**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

***Here is an example,*** (see comments in code) to be added inside `formvalidation.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();

// all other codes you already have

$name = "John"; // this is an example
// replace above with your POST variable
// such as $name = $_POST['name'];

$_SESSION['showname'] = $name;

header("Location: your_other_file.php");

exit; // keep this
```

**N.B.:** Make sure there is nothing else above `<?php session_start();` such as your form, because this will throw a warning, stating `Headers already sent...`

**your_other_file.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['showname'])){

    $name = $_SESSION['showname'];

    echo $name;

}
```

---

`$name = "John"; // this is an example`

Replace above in code with your POST variable. 
Such as `$name = $_POST['name'];` as an example, since you have not provided additional code as to what your [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) variable is for the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session feature to call the variable instead of including a page, because it will indeed load an entire page. Please be more specific about your goal, perhaps we can help more by knowing more.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `include 'someFile.php';` it's like you are taking all the contents of that file and pasting it in the code. For example if I had:

*someFile.php*

```
echo '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
echo '<p>I like pie</p>';
```

then:

```
include 'someFile.php';
echo $name;
```

Is the same as:

```
echo '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
echo '<p>I like pie</p>';
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to execute whatever's in formvalidation.php. All the include function does is basically replace that line with the contents of your included file.

So if you don't want to show what's in that file - enclose the entire file in a function, or multiple functions.  This is the way your library files (that you include) should be.  Nothing in that file should be outside of a function definition.

Example (it's a crappy programming practice, but for example) -

formvalidation.php was ->

```
<?php 
   echo "hola";
   if ($i = 5) {
      echo 15;
   }
?>
<form><input type="text" value= "10"/>
<?php
   echo "macho, macho man.";
?>
```

Everything gets shown when I include it.

formvalidation.php now ->

```
<?php 
   function validate_form() {
     echo "hola";
     if ($i = 5) {
        echo 15;
     }
?>
<form><input type="text" value= "10"/>
<?php
     echo "macho, macho man.";
   }
?>
```

Now the way I've changed the file - nothing will get printed until I call validate_form();

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The whole HTML content of formvalidation.php will come up on the screen (so everything outside of `<?php ?>` just like all the outputs (echo etc ...) of the included file will come up on the screen.

You can avoid that by removing the outputs and only putting functions and variable declarations into the included file formvalidation.php.

The content of formvalidation.php could eg. be:

```
<?php
$name = 'test';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, that's what include does.  I assume that you define `$name` inside the formvalidation.php file and that is why you are including it.

The right solution here would be to seperate the code in formvalidation.php into a function/class/file which does the data processing and another which creates the output.  The you include/call only the first in the situation where you don't want the output

However, it is possible to capture the output and then discard it, using output buffering:

```
<?php 
ob_start(); //Start capturing output
include 'formvalidation.php'; 
ob_end_clean(); // Stop capturing output and discard whatever was captured
echo $name;
?>
```

That said I would really **not** recommend this.  The recommended way to fix this is to seperate your back-end code from your output generating code and only call what you actually need in any given situation.

**Edit**

An example of how to seperate the issues properly could be the following.

Lets assume your current formvalidation.php is something like:

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
if( '' == $name ){ ?>
   <p class="error">You must supply a name</p>
   <form action="foo.php">
      <input name="name" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form><?php
} else {
   echo '<p>Form valid!</p>';
}
```

In a new file validator.php you could do:

```
<?php
class MyValidator{
   public $name;

   function read_data(){
      $this->name = $_REQUEST['name'];
   }

   function validate(){
        if( '' == $name ){ ?>
           <p class="error">You must supply a name</p>
           <form action="foo.php">
              <input name="name" />
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
           </form><?php
        } else {
           echo '<p>Form valid!</p>';
        }
   }
}
```

Then you change you formvalidtion.php to

```
<?php
require_once 'validator.php';
$val = new MyValidator();
$val->read_data();
$val->validate();
```

While the file you have above becomes

```
<?php
require_once 'validator.php';
$val = new MyValidator();
$val->read_data();
echo $val->name;
```